# Group by and aggregate to create a map

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to create a map using group by:

I/P

```
Col1|DATE| Col2|   Val1| 

|A| 2016|  1|20170315|
|B| 2012|  1|20130306|
|C| 2016|  1|20210318|
```

O/P

```
{
"new_date": "20170315#Col2"
"new_struct":{ "A": "20170315", "C": "20210318"}
},
{
"new_date": "20130306#Col2"
"new_struct":{ "B": "20130306"}
}

new_df = df.groupBy("DATE").\
    agg(func.collect_list(func.create_map(func.col("Col1"),
    func.col("Val1"))).alias("new_struct"))
```

But above code creates an array rather than struct. Can you please advise on correct way to address this?

Comment: Do you mean a Map instead of Struct? Correct?

Comment: yes. Above snippet provides me with a list. Am looking to get map.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with this solution:

```
df_tmp.groupBy("DATE").agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list(F.col("Col1")),F.collect_list(F.col("Val1"))).alias("new_struct"))
```

Comment: be aware that if you have duplicated keys it will throw an error for example:

DATE=2000, Col1=A and DATE=2000, Col1=A

If you want to remove the duplicated keys, you can set spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy to LAST_WIN so that the key inserted at last takes precedence.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I am actually dropping duplicates before passing the dataframe in Groupby but this is really a nice information to know.